# SQL script for special data representation

Tags: sql, join, cross-join

Please help me with my problem of data representation.

I have some SQL script, that creates the following data presentation:

```
Declare params cursor for 
Select distinct id_variable from [UIR_DB].[dbo].[Variable_Values]
open params
Declare @idparam int
Declare @csql nvarchar(max)  = ''
Declare @csql2 nvarchar(max)  = ''
declare @csq13 nvarchar(max) = ''
Declare @i int = 1
fetch next from params into @idparam
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
Select @csql2 = @csql2 +', id_var'+LTRIM(Str(@i))+ ', param' +LTrim(Str(@i))
Select @csql =  ' (Select id_variable as id_var'+LTrim(Str(@i))+', value as param'+LTrim(Str(@i))+' from
[UIR_DB].[dbo].[Variable_Values] where id_variable = '+LTrim(Str(@idparam))+') a'+LTrim(Str(@i))+'
cross join'+@csql
Set @i = @i+1
fetch next from params into @idparam
end
Select @csql = 'Select '+SubString(@csql2,2,LEN(@csql2)-1)+' from
'+SubString(@csql,1,LEN(@csql)-11)+'order by'+SubString(@csql2,2,LEN(@csql2)-1)
print @csql
exec sp_executesql @csql
close params
deallocate params
```

[image: execute Script 1]

My knowledge of SQL not so far, so please, if it wouldn't be a big problem, i need script, that will creates the next data representation from Script1 results:
[image: New script results]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

you can add your first result set into one temp table and perform following query.

you can add alias or id as per you requriment.

```
SELECT id_var1,Param1 FROM [UIR_DB].[dbo].[Variable_Values]
UNION
SELECT id_var2,Param2 FROM [UIR_DB].[dbo].[Variable_Values]
```

Comment: it should be a dinamic sql query, because it can be more, that variable1 and variable2.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you. This can be done in 2 steps

1) Generate auto increment number for records in result set

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id_var1) AS id_sample,
  [id_var1], [param1],[id_var2], [param2]
  FROM Table1
)
```

Note : you can add incremental number in your code, the above is just example

2) Use below query to get desired result

```
SELECT 
c.id_sample,
c.id_variable
,c.value
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  (id_sample,id_var1,param1),
  (id_sample,id_var2,param2)
)c(id_sample,id_variable,value)
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/653fc/1)

Comment: it should be dinamic sql query, because it can be more, that variable1 and variable2.